# RegExp.exec() returns null when called repeatedly in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, regex, firefox

I've encountered an issue using the regex function exec() in Firefox 10 and 11.

The function seems to behave erratic when it is called a lot. Among the correct result, it also returns `null` a lot. From Safari 5.1.3, Chrome 18 and the above mentioned Firefox versions, I can see the issue only within Firefox.

I've created a JSFiddle to demonstrate the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/KSH3S/ , source:

```
var i, x = "";

for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    var matches = /foo/g.exec('sdkfjfooasdknal');
    x += matches + "<br>";
}

$('body').html(x);
```

In my two Firefox versions, this returns 40x `foo`, 1x `null`, 41x `foo`, and from then on it swaps between these two on every single call.

Have you encountered this?

Comment: What happens if it is invoked using the *same* regex object? (e.g. `var foo = /foo/g` outside the loop)

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve?  Calling `exec()` repeatedly on a regular expression with the "g" flag accumulates some state from one call to the next to allow you to find multiple matches in the same source string.

Comment: @jfriend00 But it's a *new* regex object in this case, and even if that *were* the case, it should be a predictable pattern. The issue is that FF behaves erratically.

Comment: @pst - Are you sure it's a new regex object?  JS has function scope, not block scope.

Comment: @jfriend00 variables are scoped to functions. objects are not. `/foo/g` constructs a new RegExp object, just as `"foo"` constructs a new string object. Unless of course there is some "funny caching" going on (perhaps after the 80th such RegExp construction?). In any case, still not an explanation for erratic behavior :-)

Comment: tested it in FF and Chrome and Chrome worked fine and in FF it appeared to follow the pattern described in the question.

Comment: I repeat the question - what problem is really trying to be solved here?  Obviously, this is a messy way to work that has some inconsistent behavior.  The sane developer would find a less controversial (e.g. bug ridden) way of solving the problem.  Unless the whole point of this question is to try to delve into this esoteric issue in which case I'll spend my time on more practical issues.

Comment: @jfriend00 The question is **What causes FireFox to behave [incorrectly in] this fashion?** The answer is likely "bug report #xyz". In any case, it's a valid question. There may be a case where such a pattern is used (e.g. this might be a minimized example) and FireFox is *failing* to work as expected.

Comment: @pst - you can pursue an answer that way if you want (go delve through thousands of Firefox bugs reports if you want to).  I'm more interested in finding a safe way to solve the problem that doesn't run afoul of browser bugs and implicitly declaring a regex like was being done looked like potential trouble-causing code to me from the very start so it isn't something I'd write in the first place.  Either explicitly declare a new regex inside the loop or declare it outside the loop and explicitly use the same object.  One or the other is much safer.  And, that's the type of answer I've proposed.

Comment: @jfriend00 I find that silly. I expect `1 + 1` to be `2`. A flaw in the core expectations should be *identified* and not *ignored*. The answers provided give insight, and demonstrate *work-abouts* which are practical solutions that first *require that the problem is identified*. (E.g. That there is a bug. Good. Now let's move on. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I've been using RegExp.exec() in a mousemove context (collision detection, parsing style attribute), so it got called many times. Your replies helped a lot!

Comment: @snwflk Glad you have a work-about :-) As jfriend00 noted, the `/g` switch here is 1) not needed and 2) may cause the bug as FF is likely incorrectly caching the object (*with* state). I would recommend *removing* the `/g` in this context. (There is no point to `/g` unless *saving* the RegExp object to use later).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has something to do with the implicit declaration of the regex inside the loop.  My guess is that the browser is caching it somewhere or getting confused by that somehow.

If you explicitly create a new regex object each time through the `for` loop, then Firefox no longer has a problem with this:

```
var x = "";

for (var i=0; i<10000; i++) {
    var re = new RegExp("foo", "g");
    var matches = re.exec( 'sdkfjfooasdknal' );
    x += matches+"<br>";
}

$('body').html( x );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/F49db/

And, it doesn't matter which way you explicitly declare the regex as this method works also:

```
var x = "";

for (var i=0; i<10000; i++) {
    var re = /foo/g;
    var matches = re.exec( 'sdkfjfooasdknal' );
    x += matches+"<br>";
}

$('body').html( x );
```

Comment: +1 For showing that it may be related to the RegExp literal somehow. I do also suspect it has to do with the VM caching, as might be explained with the 40-good (new), 40-null (reused first 40 with `/g`?), alternating cycles (reusing in cycle with `/g`?).

Comment: The statement "if you explicitly create" is wrong. As the answer(s) show the *work-about* is that **using an intermediate variable** eliminates the issue in FF. In all cases the same number of regex objects *should* have been created. Presumably without the variable FF aggressively caches the RegExp object a wee bit too much. (e.g. it didn't notice the `/g` or assumed it would never be used in an immediate-value situation.)

Comment: (My argument is that `re = /foo/g; re.exec` is no more "explicitly creating" than `(/foo/g).exec`. In both cases there is exactly one RegExp object literal.)

Comment: @pst - I'm not arguing that there should be a difference between the two cases, but obviously there is.  And explicitly creating a new regex object and assigning it to another variable makes it harder for the interpreter to do anything other than what you wanted.  Obviously the OP's case has run into some edge cases (probably caching related) and using the intermediate variable pulls the interpreter away from the edge cases to force it to behave properly.

Comment: Again, there is *no difference in **creating** the objects*. The difference is in the variable assignment (or removing the direct usage in the expression, as noted).

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug in the JS engine in Firefox, like jfriend00 says.  Should be fixed in Firefox 12.  See  https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=728021

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial explanation.  If you try [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KSH3S/2/) it seems to work fine. So the problem or bug might be in the regex parsing of a literal?  I'm not sure, but could it be something where the loop optimization treats the literal differently than the variable.

Here is the fiddle code:

```
var x = "";

for (var i=0; i<10000; i++) {
    var a='sdkfjfooasdknal';
    var b=/foo/g;
    var matches = b.exec(a);
    x += matches+"<br>";
}

$('body').html( x );​
```

UPDATE:
Here is something I tried to force it out of a normal loop and the problem reappeared.
Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xXYdF/.

```
var x = "";
i=200;
function reg(){
    var matches = /foo/g.exec('sdkfjfooasdknal');
    x += matches+"<br>";
}
    function run(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    if(i--){
      reg();
      run();
      $('body').html( x );
    }
  },10);
}

run();
```

Comment: +1 For half-counter jfriend00 and showing it's not a function of being a RegExp literal. Still likely related to caching and object re-used, would be my guess.

Comment: @pst - How is this a counter of my idea?  This has an explicit re-declaration of the regex inside the loop just like mine.  They used `var b = /foo/g` rather than `new RegExp()`, but either way it's an explicit creation of a new object each time through the loop.

Comment: FYI, breaking the string out into the separate `a` variable does not make a difference here.  What makes this one work is that the regex is explicitly recreated each time through the loop.

Comment: @jfriend00 I kind of guessed that, but I was just trying different things to see what happened.  To make it clearer I probably should have undone that.

Comment: @jfriend00 It's a **half-counter** *because it does not use the RegExp constructor* but rather *still uses the RegExp literal*. I agree with the conclusion (that it's a bug), but not the cause (literal vs. explicit constructor invocation). The *work-about* is thus **using a variable** and not switching to `new RegExp`.