# Create a jquery Margin adder class

Tags: jquery, html, css, automation, margin

I am looking for a way to add margin with any number with jquery.
It should be something like :

```
<div class="mr5">Add this text margin-right = 5px</div>
<div class="ml15">Add this text margin-left = 15px</div>
<div class="mt6">Add this text margin-top = 6px</div>
<div class="mb4">Add this text margin-bottom = 4px</div>
```

and etc ...

```
<div class="m4">Add this text margin = 4px</div>
<div class="p4">Add this text padding = 4px</div>
...
```

Is it possible to create jquery code to do this ?
Maybe do it for padding to.

**Idea :**  it can used in Bootstrap too , like add automatic padding , margin or even `font-size` with `fs18` to add font-size:18px

Thanks

Comment: What about using jQuery `.css()` for example `$(".mr5").css("margin-right":"5px")`? See http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp.

Comment: Thanks Mirabilis But , I just want to create a automatic code to add any margin with any number ...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. Elaborate?

Comment: Oh I see if the below question is what solves your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an options. It will work with padding too.

pass in the 'start with' class and the css you want to apply.

it will then use regex to get the value to apply and `css` to apply it.

```js
function addCss(startClass, css) {
  $('[class^="' + startClass + '"]').each(function() {
    var px, reg = new RegExp(startClass + "(\\d+)", 'g');
    if ((px = reg.exec(this.className)) != null) {
      $(this).css(css, px[1] + 'px');
    }
  });
}

addCss('mr', 'margin-right');
addCss('ml', 'margin-left');
addCss('mt', 'margin-top');
addCss('mb', 'margin-bottom');

//addCss('pl', 'padding-left');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="mr5">Add this text margin-right = 5px</div>
<div class="ml15">Add this text margin-left = 15px</div>
<div class="mt6">Add this text margin-top = 6px</div>
<div class="mb4">Add this text margin-bottom = 4px</div>
<div class="mb40">Add this text margin-bottom = 4px</div>
<div class="mb4">Add this text margin-bottom = 4px</div>
<div class="mb400">Add this text margin-bottom = 4px</div>
<div class="mb4">Add this text margin-bottom = 4px</div>
```

Comment: I am getting this error : TypeError: (intermediate value).exec(...) is null

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167323/regexp-exec-returns-null-when-called-repeatedly-in-firefox). I have updated the answer to split up the regex.

Comment: Excuse me Dear Ben bun I am getting this error now : TypeError: reg.exec(...) is null

Comment: Great ... Thank you buddy

Answer (score 1):

Please try this :

```
$("div").each(function(){
        var _thiss = $(this);
        var div_class = $(this).attr("class");
      var margin = div_class.split("_");

      if(margin[0] == "mr"){
        $(_thiss).css({"margin-right":margin[1]+"px"});
      }
      if(margin[0] == "ml"){
        $(_thiss).css({"margin-left":margin[1]+"px"});
      }
    });
```

Comment: Add your classes write css accordingly and small change in class to `mr_5, ml_15` etc

Comment: and that is dynamically get your margins. please check this : https://jsfiddle.net/34djvdtu/6/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".mr5").css("margin-right", "5px");
$(".ml15").css("margin-right", "15px");
$(".mt6").css("margin-right", "6px");
$(".mb4").css("margin-right", "4px");
```

Add this to page loader or where ever you wish?